# How to get roboguice's bindings

Tags: android, interface, gson, roboguice

I am using RoboGuice and Gson in my application

at some point, i need gson to inject a json into an interface, however, Gson doesnt know how to inject an interface, unless you provide an instance creator, that maps between an implementation class and its interface

the same way with roboguice, it also needs this exact same mapping.

in order to test my application, i want to give roboguice and gson the same implementation mapping

how do i get a hold of roboguice's bound implementations of my interfaces, in order to pass them to the GsonBuilder InstanceCreator ?

Answer (score 0):

Roboguice (well, Guice) actually *is* able to "inject into an interface", that's what it's designed to do.
Let's say that you have the following code:

```
public class ExampleClass {
    @Inject InterfaceType mExampleField;
    ...
```

Guice will affect it the *concrete* subtype of `InterfaceType` you bound to `InterfaceType` in your injection configuration when you inject an `ExampleClass` instance. Let's say the module you initialize your injector with looks like this:

```
public class ExampleModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override 
    protected void configure() {
        bind(InterfaceType.class).to(ConcreteType.class);
    }
}
```

provided the following definitions:

```
public interface InterfaceType { }

public class ConcreteType implements InterfaceType { ... }
```

If you inject an `ExampleClass` somewhere now, e.g.

```
@Inject ExampleClass mExample;
```

then `mExample.mExampleField` will reference a `ConcreteType` object.

Now, my understanding is that what you're wanting to do is build a an entity of the concrete class your Guice module binds to `InterfaceType`. You could do something like this:

```
public class ExampleClass {
    @Inject InterfaceType mDummyExampleField;

    private final Gson mGson = ...;

    ...

    public InterfaceType buildBoundSubTypeFromJson(final String json) {
        return mGson.fromJson(json, mDummyExampleField.getClass());
    }
}
```

and Guice will dynamically look for the concrete type of the instance referenced by `mExampleField` to create an object of this type. mExampleField is populated by the injector so it will be of the concrete type you bound `InterfaceType` interface to.

This means that in the above example `buildBoundSubTypeFromJson()` will returns objects of actual type `ConcreteType`.

Or, slightly cleaner:

```
public class Deserializer {
    private final Class<? extends InterfaceType> mConcreteType;

    @Inject
    public Deserializer(final InterfaceType dummy) {
        mConcreteType = dummy.getClass();
    }

    private final Gson mGson = ...;

    ...

    public InterfaceType buildBoundSubTypeFromJson(final String json) {
        return mGson.fromJson(json, mConcreteType);
    }
}
```

So that works, but I think it would be quite dangerous, because the Json string would have to match the actual type you bound your interface to depending on your current injection settings, or all subtypes of the interface would have to match a common json format, both of which can't be enforced statically.

Another slightly stronger solution would be to have a unique entity type you deserialize your Json data into (assuming the case where Json data is always the same), then convert it to an `InterfaceType` through a converter object which could be injected (and bound to the one of its subtype which matches the type `InterfaceType` is bound to).

Also note that you could retrieve the type dynamically from the Guice by visiting its configuration like this:

```
injector
    .getBinding(InterfaceType.class)
    .acceptTargetVisitor(new DefaultBindingTargetVisitor<InterfaceType, InterfaceType>() {
        @Override
        public InterfaceType visit(LinkedKeyBinding<? extends InterfaceType> binding) {
            mConcreteType = binding.getLinkedKey().getTypeLiteral());
            return visitOther(binding);
        }

        // don't forget to override other visit methods if you except other types of bindings !
    });
```

if you want to make it a bit less hacky.

---

So it looks like you're trying to deserialize in a type which has a field declared of an interface type, as in:

```
ExampleClass example = mGson.fromJson(json, ExampleClass.class);
```

and the `example.mExampleField` here is null. This is normal because Gson has no way of knowing what object you want to be instantiated for `mExampleField`.

The solution for this problem is to use [custom deserialization](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html), which means *you* control Gson's deserialization process for that type.

Combined with the first problem about getting the concrete type from injection settings, this should look somewhat like:

```
class ExampleDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<InterfaceType>() {
    private final Class<? extends InterfaceType> mConcreteType;

    @Inject
    public ExampleDeserializer(final InterfaceType dummy) {
        mConcreteType = dummy.getClass();
    }

    @Override
    public InterfaceType deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return context.deserialize(json, mConcreteType);
    }
```

}

and don't forget to register this custom deserializer where you create your `Gson` instance:

```
public class AnotherClass {
    private final Gson mGson;

    @Inject
    public AnotherClass(ExampleDeserializer mExampleDeserializer) {
        mGson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(InterfaceType.class, mExampleDeserializer).create();
        // now you can deserialize ExampleClass Json representation using mGson
    }
}
```

Comment: my problem is when i try to deserialize a json string that contains an object that is written in the pojo as an interface, it leaves this as null, will this fix the problem ?

Comment: this is yet another problem, I updated my answer with how to address it in your use case. Also added a note about the fact that you could use Guice bindings visitors.